# Приложение Android на SD карте

Tags: android

Сложно ли переписать программный код Android приложения, чтобы оно могло устанавливаться на SD карту? С чего стоит начать и что почитать?

Comment: [гляньте тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947689/move-applications-to-sd-card)